# Caught in a loop of errors with importing modules in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, module

I am attempting to use the query-string npm package with typescript.

I am getting the error when I am run the `npm start` command that can be found in my `package.json` file.

When I use `import queryString from "query-string"` I get an error `require() of ES Module {...path/.js} from {...path/.ts} is not supported`

In my `tsconifg.json` file I have `module: "CommonJS"` set, which is what I believe is causing the issue. However when I attempt to change this to any ES module, I get the `Cannot use import outside of module` node error.

When I try to set `type: "module` in my `package.json` I get a `Unknown file extension ".ts" for {...path/index.ts}`

Any help to get out of the this loop of errors would be great!

Thank you

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": [
        "es6",
        "dom"
    ],
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "lib"
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
}
```

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "personal-typescript",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "npm run build:live",
        "build": "tsc -p .",
        "build:live": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --exec \"ts-node\" src/index.ts"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
        "@types/node": "^18.11.19",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
        "query-string": "^8.1.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "typescript": "^4.9.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.18.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your package.json and tsconfig file?

Comment: in compiler options, try putting this "include": ["/**/*.ts"] . You can also read a bit more about it here https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include

Comment: I did add that to my tsconfig, but I am still getting the `require() of ES Module {...path/.js} from {...path/.ts} is not supported` error

Comment: your package.json is missing type:module

Comment: When I add `type: "module"` to package.json I get `Unknown file extension ".ts" for {path/.ts}`error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251629/discussion-between-jorge-guerreiro-and-gmeeker99).